# In python, How to do Conditional formatting in MSExcel cell referring another cell

Tags: python, conditional-formatting

Hi I want to perform conditional value on a cell, that refers to another cell.
Below is the code I am using to color the cells from A2:J20, 
based on the cells BE2:KE20 with values as FALSE

I tried this code it works fine, but when I open the excel file it is throwing an error, stating the formula is wrong

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                             'font_color': '#9C0006'})
worksheet1 = writer.sheets['Difference_Sheet'] 
worksheet1.conditional_format('A2:J20', {'type': 'cell',
                                       'criteria': '= $BE2 = FALSE',
                                       'value' : 'FALSE',
                                       'format': format1})
```

Could anyone tell where is the error

Answer (score 1):

```
format1 = book.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                         'font_color': '#9C0006'})

worksheet1.conditional_format('A2:J20', {'type': 'formula',
                                  'criteria': '=RIGHT($BE2,10)= "FALSE"', 
                                  'format': format1})
```

You were close, you just need to make a couple changes.